# Issue in maintaining the relationship between multiple tables in core data?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift2

I want fetch the data from multiple tables and for that I have to join multiple tables but I don't know how to do that in core data just because I am a beginner . I wrote a raw query as follows

```
select main.city.city from city,pincode
 WHERE
  (main.city.id = main.pincode.city_id)
 AND 
  (main.pincode.pincode = 400001)
```

please help me with same query how can i write in core data?

Comment: you need to read about `CoreData` first. You cannot execute queries with `CoreData` like you do with `SQLite`.

Comment: here's a [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/14742/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-how-to-work-with-relations-and-predicates) about the core data relationships. I would suggest that you go through all the tutorials of this series.

Comment: I read it but I am not getting how to do same operation in Coredata if i want.

Comment: can you suggest tutorials for swift?

Comment: you can read this https://www.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial

Comment: however just google "core data tutorial swift" and you'll get gazillion of suggestions.